# JavaScript Variable Undefined, but it is not

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

So I have the following JavaScript which pulls user data from Facebook:

[image]

As you can see in that snippet I have included the line 'console.log(full_name);', which when ran successfully outputs the users full name into the browser console.

Then when I try this:

```
<script>document.write('Hello, ' + full_name);</script>
```

It doesn't work. It comes back with `Uncaught ReferenceError: full_name is not defined`.

I am confused as it is clearly defined & works when using `console.log`. Someone help?

Comment: Please include your code as text, not an image.

Comment: the variable is in the same scope ?

Comment: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Not enough to go on here. Where is the document.write line in relation to the rest of this code?

Comment: Declare the variable?

Comment: You want to initialize your vars first - i.e. `var full_name = response.name;`. You can also go straight for the response object - i.e. `console.log(response.full_name)` to see if you're getting values from `response`.

Comment: Most likely, you are trying to access the variable before the ajax callback function runs. The function is asynchronous (see @Andreas's link). Which means you can't access the variable as soon as you might expect. (This is a very common error, anyway).

Comment: @Justin3o9 "_document.write is going to execute once the page is rendered_"  It will be executed as soon as the browser hits the script block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to render the name on the page. However, as @Andreas pointed out the document.write is executed as soon as that block is hit, which is before your Facebook API call is returned. Instead, try placing an id on the element you want the name to be rendered in and use getElementById within your callback. Something like this.

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = response.name;
});
```

Also, as others have mentioned, you are polluting your global scope with many variables by placing them within your call back without the var keyword.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Just before you posted your reply I had tried this solution myself and it worked, so I will mark your post as being the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>document.write('Hello, ' + full_name);</script>
```

you don't define the global variable full_name.

Comment: I didn't state 'var' inside the function & it wasn't defined before that function so therefore it's already a global variable. Also as you can see I have already chosen the answer that worked for me & you have clearly not read the other replies before posting.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely would throw an error.

Assuming that you are including the line

```
<script>document.write('Hello, ' + full_name);</script>
```

in the HTML directly, it will be executed much before the call **getLoginStatus** of fb API completes, which is where you have defined the global variable **full_name**

Not to mention this is a bad practice (Declaring global variables), but it is.

Comment: Not just that, the OP isn't attaching `full_name` to `window`, so the inline script wouldn't work.

Comment: True. But it also depends if the code OP posted as image is inline. Then he doesn't have to...

Answer (score 0):

In your example, invoking `console.log(full_name)` works because it's defined within that code. Referencing `full_name` in the inline script you specified won't work as it can't access the scope of the callback you pass to `getLoginStatus`; more specifically, in your example, it will look for `full_name` on the global object, which is `window` in the case of the browser. Thus, `window.full_name` is correctly `undefined`. In any case, there's also no guarantee that your callback will have been invoked by the time you invoke `document.write`.

To remedy this, you'll need to call `document.write` within your callback or store the value elsewhere for later retrieval. As an aside, you should [avoid `document.write`](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/04/10/dont-docwrite-scripts/).

Smashing Magazine has an [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) on JavaScript scope.

Comment: I would however add a link to document.write(), instead of document.open(), if I referenced this.

Comment: That think does state: "Also, an automatic document.open() call happens when document.write() is called after the page has loaded, but that's not defined in the W3C specification.", but I guess I can point to some best practices document.